Is there a way to wait approval result in Power Plarforms Approvals Kit?
I have been experimenting with Power Platforms Approvals Kit.
(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IxenSFO8gOM intro to those who are not familiar)
I know that when I create a normal approval in Power Automate I can wait the response value in the flow and then continue flow based on the approval result.
But I wonder if there is a similar option to wait Approvals Kit in a flow as well? For example if I want to make changes to Sharepoint files, is there a way to trigger those actions after approver has approved in Approvals Kit?
